# Conservation of Mass, Momentum and Energy - Airburst Rounds

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, mass, momentum

I have a airburst round with set amount of fragments with a certain shape inside my bullet.  After a certain distance has travelled, a charge explodes in the back of the round disintegrating the shell and sending the fragments out in a forward cone.

My problem :

1. Why do they shoot out in a cone? Or put in another way, why does a shotgun shell's fragments form a cone spread?
2. Would it be possible to choose a charge size/shape so that the discharge angle can be controlled?
3. Should every fragment be modelled separately after the explosion or can they be modelled as whole?

Comment: Jinawee, thank you that you took the time to edit my post, but please, do not my remove my greetings and my thank you for any help.  I posted it with those phrases to be polite and I believe removing them is not a decent move.  Thank you.

Comment: 22134484: the site convention is not to clutter up your posts with introductions and thank yous. jinawee was quite correct to remove them. This doen't mean we're an unhelpful bunch - quite the opposite in fact as we're always happy to help and don't need any social greasing :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer this in 2D, although the 3D case is very similar. Modeling the explosion as throwing out a wave of particles with velocity $v_p$ in all directions, if the projectile is initially traveling with translational velocity vector $\mathbf{v}_t$ then the fragments after airburst will be traveling with velocity vectors
$$\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{v}_t+\mathbf{s}$$
where 
$$|\mathbf{s}|=v_p.$$
It's clear that this set of vectors is just the points on a circle of radius $v_p$ centered at $\mathbf{v}_t$, so choosing $\mathbf{v}_t=(v_t,0)$, they're solutions of 
$$(x-v_t)^2+y^2=v_p^2.$$
Assuming $v_t>v_p$, this takes the form of a circle whose points all satisfy $x>0$, and thus it's visually apparent that this forms a cone-shaped angular distribution. If this is not obvious, one can solve 
$$(x-v_t)^2+y^2=v_p^2\\y=\tan(\theta)x,$$
differentiate each of the two solutions with respect to $\theta$, compute their vector norms and then add them to obtain an unnormalized angular distribution function, which can be normalized by dividing by the circle perimeter $2\pi v_p$ to get
$$I(\theta)=\frac{1}{2\pi} \left(\sqrt{\frac{v_t \left(\cos (2 \theta ) v_t-2 \cos ^2(\theta )
   \sqrt{\sec ^2(\theta ) v_p^2-\tan ^2(\theta ) v_t^2}\right)+v_p^2}{v_p^2-\sin
   ^2(\theta ) v_t^2}}+\sqrt{\frac{v_t \left(2 \cos ^2(\theta ) \sqrt{\sec
   ^2(\theta ) v_p^2-\tan ^2(\theta ) v_t^2}+\cos (2 \theta )
   v_t\right)+v_p^2}{v_p^2-\sin ^2(\theta ) v_t^2}}\right)$$
which has singularities at 
$$\theta_\pm=\pm\sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{v_p}{v_t}\right).$$
This is why you observe a conical fragment distribution, and the cone half-angle is given by $|\theta_\pm|$.

Here is Mathematica code to derive the formula I used (hit `Cell > Convert To > StandardForm` to get the subscripts to parse correctly):

```
points = {x, y} /. Solve[(x - Subscript[v, t])^2 + y^2 == 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(v\), \(p\), \(2\)]\) && 
     y == Tan[\[Theta]] x, {x, y}];
Dpoints = \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(\[Theta]\)]points\);
AngularDensity = 
 1/(2 \[Pi] Subscript[v, p])Simplify[
   Sqrt[Dpoints[[1]].Dpoints[[1]]] + Sqrt[Dpoints[[2]].Dpoints[[2]]], 
   Assumptions -> {0 <= Subscript[v, p] <= Subscript[v, t]}]
```

The singularities are found by solving for when when the denominator is zero.

Here is a plot of the angular density for various explosion velocities and projectile speeds:

```
Plot[Evaluate[
  Table[Piecewise[{{AngularDensity, -ArcSin[
          Subscript[v, p]/Subscript[v, t]] <= \[Theta] <= 
        ArcSin[Subscript[v, p]/Subscript[v, t]]}, {0, True}}] /. 
    Subscript[v, t] -> 1, {Subscript[v, p], 0.05, 0.95, 
    0.1}]], {\[Theta], -Pi/2, Pi/2}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
 Exclusions -> None, PlotStyle -> Table[Hue[(k - 1)/12], {k, 10}], 
 Background -> Black, FrameStyle -> White, 
 PlotLabel -> 
  Style["Unnormalized Angular Fragment Distribution\n\
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(v\), \(t\)]\) = 1, \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(v\), \
\(p\)]\) =    {0.05 (red), 0.15 (orange), ... , 0.95 (violet)}", 
   Orange], 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["Angle (\[Theta])", Orange], 
   Style["Fragment Probability", Orange]}, PlotRange -> {0, 8}, 
 PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

Minor notes: The expression $I(\theta)$ incorrectly evaluates to nonzero values when $|\theta|>|\theta_\pm|$, when in fact it obviously should evaluate to zero (since there are no fragments outside the cone). This error is due to the fact that imaginary values are obtained for the solutions of the circle-line intersection outside this cone angle, which turn into positive real numbers when you take the norm. So to correctly plot it, you need to use $I(\theta)$ inside the cone and zero outside the cone.

Comment: It is no need.  The info you supplied me with will help me in my research.  I thank you for your help!

Comment: If you could perhaps direct me to your sources, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: @22134484: I had no sources, I just derived it based on the visual picture I described. I edited my answer to include the CAS derivation and some pictures of the distribution function.

Comment: This is absolutely beautiful.  This describes exactly what I need! Thank you for your time, it must have taken a while.  I wish I could give you some rep, but I need 15 to do so.  With that said, I give you hypothetical rep.  Thank you

Comment: @22134484: Thanks. That said, if this is for a game and you're trying to model fragment distributions, the big complicated expression I gave is probably overkill, and you could probably use any other easy-to-implement cone-shaped distribution and no one would know the difference. The cone angle $\theta_\pm=\pm\sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{v_p}{v_t}\right)$ is simple enough though, and is always valid, so you could use that to estimate the width of the cone, and use some easy-to-implement distribution for the fragments within the cone.

Comment: This is not for a game.  I am modelling a Airburst Round for my Transport Theory I project.  I plan to do the motion in general of the projectile as 2D, but the Airburst in 3D in such a way that I plot the results on a "target" to indicate projectile spread.  Thank you for the help once again.  How do you prefer I reference you in my report?

Comment: @22134484: Not sure how reference work, maybe just include a link to this thread or something? I edited my answer to be properly normalized and updated the plot of probabilities; due to being normalized, it now correctly shows that for small cone angles the fragments are more concentrated like a beam, and for wide cone angles it's less intense.

Answer (score 0):

For (1), consider the $x$ and $y$-components of momentum, which we know must be conserved--each component is conserved individually.  For (2), what factors control the components from (1)?  For (3), how many fragments are expected?

Comment: For 2 : There is a initial speed at which the projectile travels and the explosive force of the charge.  I do not know why it fans out in a cone shape.  It is the same with a shotgun shell.  I assume drag has the largest influence on the shape of the cone in the shotgun example.  And for 3 : The amount of fragments are about 50-60 fragments.

Comment: @22134484: It expands in a cone shape because the angular distribution of fragments has a singularity in its probability distribution function. I'll post it as an answer in a moment.

Comment: For the exploding shell, treat the actual explosion as instantaneous and giving some velocity to each fragment, since we only care about the trajectories after the explosion is over.  Drag would affect the paths of the fragments, but we can't control drag.  If we want to choose the angle, we need factors that we can control.  For (3) you need to decide if there are enough fragments so that they can be modeled as a continuous unit: think how water, made of lots of molecules, can be modeled as continuous, but two planets orbiting a star must be modeled as discrete.

Comment: @Zach : I am thinking of putting a thin "wire" of explosives in the cylindrically shaped fragments to allow a change in angle.   The best way to picture this, is having a cylinder ( side view ) and cutting it into about 10 equal pieces.  And from the front view, I will cut it in 6 parts, like a pizza, almost.  Then the explosives in the core of the cylinder and the rear will provide a momentum shift.  PS: I do not plan to take out a car with the shrapnel.

Comment: A 1meter diameter spread will be sufficient if the round exploded, say, 5-10 meters away.  Also, what would constitute a continuous  unit?  Can the Law of Large numbers be used? Meaning, or 30+ units it can be viewed as a continuum?

Comment: "Continuous unit" how I used it meant that only the region the shrapnel occupies is important, not the individual locations of the pieces, i.e, there are enough so that if something is in the occupied region you can be confident it will be hit.  See DumpsterDoofus' answer for what goes into finding the angle.